# Can I see if a cookie set by a server exists or not in javascript?

Tags: javascript, cookies

I know that you cannot delete a cookie set by another server in javascript. Javascript can only delete cookies create by itself. But can javascript see if a cookie created by another server exists or not?

Comment: "Another server"? You mean the domain you're currently on? You can't, for instance, check if facebook set a cookie (or its value) from your own "abc.com" domain if that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope.. the problem is not with deleting..

You have no access (*whatsoever*) to cookies created by different sites (*not just servers*)..

Answer (score 2):

This isn't limited to removal. You cannot access cookies set by other domains!

Answer (score 0):

To be very short: nope...

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.cookie

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html